# Emails not sending from smtp.zoho.com in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, zoho

I am using the ZOHO email server for sending emails through my application. But it gives following error -
"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required."

```
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@xx.com"));
            msg.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@xx.com"));
            msg.From = new MailAddress("xxx@xx.com", "Test mail");
            msg.Subject = "send mail";
            msg.Body = "test MAIL....";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Host = "smtp.zoho.com";
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xx@xx.com", "XXX");
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Send(msg);
```

Comment: It seems network credential is not correct. Can you please check that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try zoho mail api https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/api/

I used this in my old project.

Although slow but resolve the problem:

```
private static void SendMail()
{
    const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://mail.zoho.com/api/accounts/{id}/messages";
    try
    {
        var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
        if (webRequest != null)
        {
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "{token}}");
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"fromAddress\": \"{email}}\"," +
                                "\"toAddress\": \"{email}}\"," +
                                "\"subject\": \"subject\"," +
                                "\"content\": \"content\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Response: {0}", result));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
```